# Secure Windows SSH Key with Windows Hello / TPM

Tags: windows, openssh, ssh-keys, tpm, windows-hello

I want to secure my Windows SSH Key with Windows Hello (my fingerprint / TPM) instead of a simple passphrase.
I found that OpenSSH can do this since v8.9 ( https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#FIDO_AUTHENTICATOR ).
Windows 10/11 comes with older Versions though, so I just installed the latest version ( `winget install Microsoft.OpenSSH.Beta` ).
After that, it kinda works. When I create an new key ( `ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk` ) Windows asks me to connect a USB sceurity key. However, I don't get Windows Hello as an option.
My Windows Hello is already set up and works fine, I use it to logon to my system and as WebAuthN key on some websites.
How do I get Windows Hello / my TPM as an option?

Comment: Have you tried other types yet? Windows Hello might not support ed25519. // Also, applications can IIRC insist on using a “real” security key.

Comment: @DanielB `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk` has the same result

Comment: The issue https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/2040 implies to me that it should work with windows hello in general 
Why wouldn't OpenSSH use Microsoft APIs? 3rd party browsers also use it.

Comment: Because it’s OpenSSH, not Windows SSH. ;) However, Microsoft has a fork with patches, which I neglected to consider. Hence, deleted. // I also found some information about how TPM chips don’t support ECC and/or that only Windows 11 22H2+ supports ECC.